# Error in adding concurrently in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mern, react-fullstack

**scripts in package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node back-end/server.js",
    "server": "nodemon back-end/server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix front-end",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

whenever I run the code using concurrently it shows me error like this

$ npm run dev

````
> concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"

[0] Error occurred when executing command: npm run server
[0] Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
[0]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
[0]     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
[1] Error occurred when executing command: npm run client
[1] Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
[1]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
[1]     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
[1] npm run client exited with code -4058
[0] npm run server exited with code -4058 ```
````

Comment: try using the full path to NPM

Comment: Which of these [Q&A search results](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+node+spawn+cmd.exe+ENOENT) have you read and tried?

Answer (score -1):

Try by replacing `"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",` with

```
"dev": "npm run server && npm run client",
```

Comment: This will not run them concurrently though